# Счастливый билет - 2

Tags: python, математика

Решаю [задачу](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=164)
. Её суть в том, чтобы определить является ли билет счастливым. Билет счастливый, если число можно разделить на две части, таким образом, чтобы сумма цифр была равная.

Написал код:

```
n = input()
c = []
for i in list(str(n)):
    c.append(int(i))
a = 0


def sum_num(a):
    while a > 9:
        e = a % 10
        a //= 10
        a += e
    return a



for i in range(0,len(c)):

    e = sum(c[:i])
    e1 = sum(c[i:])

    e = sum_num(e)
    e1 = sum_num(e1)
    if e == e1:
        print('YES')
        a = 1
        break
        
        

if a == 0:
    print('NO')
```

Но решение проходит только 17 тестов

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Answer (score 3):

Вычислим цифровой корень всего числа.

Потом на втором проходе считаем цифровой корень левой части. Если удвоенный корень левой части совпадает с корнем всего числа, то корень правой части такой же, как у левой, и билет счастливый

```
def happy(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        print('NO')
        return
    mod = 0
    for c in s:
        mod = (mod + ord(c) - ord("0")) % 9
    final = mod
    mod = 0
    for c in s:
        mod = (mod + ord(c) - ord("0")) % 9
        if (mod + mod) % 9 == final:
            print('YES')
            return
    print('NO')
    return

happy(input())
```

Как вариант - можно делать один проход, подсчитывая в списке длиной 10 количество подстрок с соотв. корнем, и в конце для финального корня найти "половинку" c ненулевым счётчиком

```
mod = 0
mods = [0]*10
for c in s:
    mod = (mod + ord(c) - ord("0")) % 9
    mods[mod] += 1

print('YES') if mods[(mod + 9 * (mod % 2)) // 2] > 0 else print('NO')
return
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def chk_lucky(ticket):
    return any(sum(map(int, ticket[i:])) == sum(map(int, ticket[:i])) for i in range(len(ticket)))
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы путаете эту задачу с похожей, где дано 6-значное число. В этой же задаче, число может быть любой длины

Comment: @Maksim ой да перепутал, ладно ща придумаю ;)

Comment: @Maksim edited ;)

Comment: Я что-то не пойму, когда эту функцию вызывать(

Comment: @Maksim `chk_lucky('0015420')` ?