# Счастливый билет (алгоритм в Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

коллеги!

Дана переменная, в которой хранится шестизначное число (номер проездного билета). Билет считается счастливым, если сумма первых трех цифр совпадает с суммой последних трех цифр номера. Вопрос: как написать в условии **сумма первых трех цифр совпадает с суммой последних трех цифр номера**?

Заранее благодарю

Comment: подсчитать одну сумму, подсчитать вторую сумму, сравнить обе  ``if sum1 == sum2``, в чем именно затруднение?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Счастливый билет - 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177778/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-2)

Comment: не понимала, как нужно правильно получить эти суммы, если мы индексы не можем применять к числам...вроде бы удалось решить и использованием map

Answer (score 1):

подсказка

1. получить последнюю цифру числа можно разделив число по модулю на 10

   ```
    digit = value % 10
   ```
2. само число после этого надо уменьшить в 10 раз и проделать 1) столько раз сколько цифр ы числа (по сути пока число не будет равно 0)

   ```
    value //= 10
   ```
3. можно сравнивать не цифры числа, а строки, т.е. превратить число в строку через функцию `str()`
4. получить 2 строки по половинке числа можно через срезы, например получить первые 4 символа строки можно так:

   ```
    part = text[:4]
   ```

а получить последние 7 символов можно так:

```
    part = text[:-7]
```

Думаю, с тем как все собрать в одну задачу вы легко справитесь

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать! Я вообще с нуля, поэтому подобные алгоритмы для меня пока сложны. Для того, чтобы числа сравнить, мне нужно преобразовать  в строки, верно?